# how to add json object to dictionary

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

when i create output with Alamofire using SwiftyJSON

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/ws/automobile/global/auction/latest/venues").responseJSON() {
        (request, response, jsonData, error) in

        var venues = JSON(jsonData!)

        println(venues)
    }
```

it appear like this in console

```
{
  "C2058" : [
    "LAA Okayama"
  ],
  "C2062" : [
    "NAA Osaka"
  ],
  "C2035" : [
    "JU Ibaraki"
  ],
  "C2526" : [
    "SMAP Fukuoka Nyusatsu"
  ],
  "C2530" : [
    "SMAP Tokyo Nyusatsu"
  ],
  "C2074" : [
    "TAA Tohoku"
  ],
  "C2008" : [
    "BCN"
  ],
  "C2012" : [
    "CAA Tokyo"
  ],
  "C2503" : [
    "L-Up PTokyoNyusatsu"
  ],
  "C2047" : [
    "JU Shizuoka"
  ],
  "C2051" : [
    "JU Yamaguchi"
  ],
  "C2086" : [
    "USS Saitama"
  ]
}
```

I want to add this to my new dictionary to use in UIPickerView,any suggestion how to do it.I am newbie to swift,code answer is really appreciated.Thank you.

What i Really want it dictionary like this
["C2047":"L-Up PTokyoNyusatsu","C2086":"USS Saitama".......]
Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know whether this is what you want:

```
var result = [String:String]()
let d = json.dictionaryValue

for (k, v) in d {
    result[k] = v.arrayValue[0].stringValue
}

println(result)
```

Comment: What i want is Like this....["C2051":"U Yamaguchi","C2086" :"USS Saitama"].Please help

Comment: @Thiha6245 Is the new edit giving you what you want?

Comment: yeah that is exactly that i want,Thank you so much

Comment: Can i ask you one more question?can you please show me how to add result to UIPickerView?Please?

Comment: @Thiha6245 To use a UIPickerView, you need to set its delegate. What does your current code looks like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166944/load-data-from-json-using-uipickerview

Comment: i updated the question at the above link..@skyline75489

Answer (score 0):

From the example you've given:

"C2058" : [
    "LAA Okayama"
  ],
  "C2062" : [
    "NAA Osaka"
  ],
  "C2035" : [
    "JU Ibaraki"
  ]

Those "C2058","C2062" are the key of Dictionary. And ["LAA Okayama"] is a String inside NSArray.
So, if you want to get the String inside NSArray. First, use the key to get value in Dictionary. Then, use NSArray to get the String.

it would like this:

```
var dict:NSDictionary=jsonData as Dictionary
var arr=dict["C2058"] as NSArray
```

and

```
println(arr[0]) //you'll see LAA Okayama
```

Comment: i don't want to create output of single value.i want to create the entire dictionary values and show them in UIPickerView.Any suggestion,please?

Comment: you're welcome. The answer from @skyline75489 is very helpful :)