# Load data from json using UIPickerView

Tags: json, swift, uipickerview, alamofire

My Current View Controller is like this

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var venuePicker : UIPickerView?

var result = [String:String]()

var resultArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.venuePicker?.delegate = self

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://example.com/xxx/xx/xx").responseJSON() {
        (request, response, jsonData, error) in

        var venues = JSON(jsonData!)

        let d = venues.dictionaryValue

        for (k, v) in venues {
            self.result[k] = v.arrayValue[0].stringValue
        }
        self.resultArray = self.result.values.array
        self.venuePicker?.reloadAllComponents()
    }

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return resultArray.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return resultArray[row]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I don't know how to show value to UIPickerView from my json dictionary.i don't want key to show at UIPickerView.I am now stuck at "?????" statement.

This is my output for result

```
[C2517: ORIX Kobe Nyusatsu, C2510: NPS Sendai Nyusatsu, C2033: JU Gunma, C2053: KAA Kyoto, C2035: JU Ibaraki, C2077: USS Gunma, C2024: ISUZU Kobe, C2505: NAA Osaka Nyusatsu, C2529: SMAP Sapporo Nyusatsu, C2502: L-Up PKobeNyusatsu, C2005: ARAI Sendai, C2072: TAA Minami Kyushu]
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to show data to a picker view, use declare 2 arrays as properties instead.

```
var resultKeys = [String]()
var resultValues = [String]()
```

Inside your `viewDidLoad` function

```
var venues = JSON(jsonData!)

let d = venues.dictionaryValue

for (k, v) in venues {
    resultKeys.append(k)
    resultValues.append(v)
}

venuePicker.dataSource = self
venuePicker.reloadAllComponents()
```

Then inside `titleForRow`

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return resultValues[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return resultValues.count
}
```

This way `resultKeys[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]` will return the key for the selected value.

Comment: i tried it.It had error in resultValues.append(v).Compiler said "JSON cannot be convertible to String" @rakeshbs.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire is totally async. It means that the block code will be executed when the data is ready. By then, the PickerView is already loaded, with an empty Array. That's the reason why the PickerView is empty. So in order to display the data we want, we need to force the PickerView to reload:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.venuePicker?.delegate = self // This should be outside the block, my bad.
    //...
    Alamofire.request(...) {in
        //...
        venuePicker?.reloadAllComponents() // hopefully this will work
    }
```

If you're not familliar with the concept of async programming, you can also choose to use sync way. Using this code I wrote https://github.com/skyline75489/swift-playground/blob/master/swift-playground%2FRequests.swift, we can easily send sync requests.

```
if let jsonData = Requests.get("YOUR_URL") {
     let venues = JSON(jsonData)
     //...
}
```

The reason why we have async is sometimes the data can be big and using sync way will cause the `viewDidLoad` to take forever to load. That's awful for user experience. However, if the data is small. Sync way can finish the task fast enough that users won't feel it. It's totally OK to use sync ways.

Comment: i got no result @skyline.i have to fix self.venuePicker?.delegate instead of yours.The program runs smoothly.But,it appear no data on picker

Comment: i have updated the code.There are no UIPickerViewDataSource and Delegate.If i add this i got error on UIViewController

Comment: Type 'ViewController' does not comform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'.it was compile time error

Comment: @Thiha6245 DataSource can be eliminated, but delegate is a must. Without delegate there won't be anything displaying on the picker view.

Comment: i fixed it by rewriting 3 func of Delegate and Datasource.But,the UIPickerView still show empty.

Comment: @Thiha6245 I think I've got the reason. You are using Alamofire, which is totally async. It means that the code in the block beginning from `var venues = JSON(jsonData!)` has **not** executed when the UIPickerView is loaded.  That's why you have nothing in the picker view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69656/discussion-between-thiha6245-and-skyline75489).

Comment: @Thiha6245 Well, async programming can be tricky and difficult, because you actually don't know when the code will be executed. I can only assume that when the code was executed, picker view is still not ready for displaying. You may want to give sync a try.